# Internet Connectivity for Ubuntu 14 in Hyper-V(Updated)

Tags: 14.04, internet, windows-10, hyper-v

**Updated**

I am having internet connectivity issues in my Hyper-V virtual ubuntu 14 machine

**Virtual Machine Internet Error Message**

[image]

**Internet Settings in Virtual Machine**

[image]

**01-Internt Settings in my Windows 10**

[image]

**02-Internt Settings in my Windows 10**
[image]

**03-Internt Settings in my Windows 10**
[image]

**04-Internt Settings in my Windows 10**
[image]

**Proxy Settings in Windows 10**

[image]

**Hyper-V Network Adapter Settings**

[image]

I am badly stucked in this Please help me out of this mess?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used MS Hyper-V, but I do use Virtualbox, GnomeBox, and currently VMware Workstation 12. It appears that you do not have a network adapter selected. Here's a picture of a VMware Machine I have. https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9X6Y.jpg

This machine is set to use NAT, and will have the same IP address as my Linux Host. I usually choose a Bridged connection, that way my guest OS will have it's own IP.

Here's another answer I found that may help you. https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access